# has_object_permission not working for detail action decorator?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an `private` action decorator for a User View. I want the action to be accessible only for the User in question.

```
# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True, permission_classes=[IsSelf])
    def private(self, request, pk):
        user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=pk)
        data = UserPrivateSerializer(user).data
        return Response(data, status=status=HTTP_200_OK)

# permissions.py
class IsSelf(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user
```

However, it looks like anyone can go to my `private` action - even if I explicitly declare `IsSelf` to be `False`:

```
class IsSelf(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # This has no effect
        return False
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FYI**:
The instance-level `has_object_permission(...)` method will only be called if the view-level `has_permission(...)` checks have already passed. Since it is inherited from `BasePermission`, the `has_permission(...)` is already returning the `True` value.

---

The **`has_object_permission(...)`** method is getting called when you call the ***`.get_object()`*** method of the `GenericAPIView`.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True, permission_classes=[IsSelf])
    def private(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        data = UserPrivateSerializer(user).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Thanks... using ```self.get_object()``` instead of ```get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=pk)``` works. What trips me up is that in my original code, the ```has_object_permission``` method would still execute (e.g. ```print```ing works) but the actual object permission wouldn't apply... do you know why that is?